# collection size and array length - sonarqube

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sonarqube

i'm using sonarqube to check the quality of our code and sonarqube has found arrays will always be greater than or equal to 0.

```
$.each(ssntxtArrayText, function (index, value) {
    if (value.length >= 0) {
        $('#resultValidation').css({
             'display': 'none',

         });
         return false;
     }
     else {                           
          $("#resultValidation").removeAttr("style");

     }
});
```

would simply changing the `if (value.length >= 0)` to `if (value.length > 0)` solve the issue or would that affect the remainder of what's going on?

Comment: what does "ssntxtArrayText" have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sonarqube has found arrays will always [have length] greater than or equal to 0.

Independent of sonarqube, this is always true in JS. I.e, your if condition is unnecessary, and your code is equivalent to

```
$.each(ssntxtArrayText, function (index, value) {
        $('#resultValidation').css({
             'display': 'none',

         });
         return false;
});
```

If this is intentional, then go ahead and remove the if statement. If this is not intentional, then the fix will depend on what the intended behavior is.

Comment: That's unnecessary, as it's never executed. If you intend it to be executed, you'll have to call it.